# Mysql Select and count number of times in another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the best SQL sentence for get the data but my sentence need 7 seconds to search and retrieve the data from a table with 9000 records.

```
 --------------     ---------------
| Table 1      |   | Table 2       |
 --------------     ---------------
| ID           |   |  ID           |
| Ticket Number|   |  ID Relation  |
 --------------    |  Ticket Number|
                    ---------------
```

So Table 1 contains the data of the ticket but 2 o more tickets can be a "grouped ticket" so the relations of this tickets are in the table 2 that contain for the same "ID Relation" every ticket is grouped.

My sentence now is:

```
SELECT T1.ID, COUNT(REPEATT2.ID)
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.TicketNumber=T1.TicketNumber
INNER JOIN Table2 REPEATT2ON REPEATT2.IDRelation=T2.IDRelation
GROUP BY T1.ID;
```

So what i am doing is with the 1st "INNER JOIN" i get the "ID Relation" and with the second "INNER JOIN" i get all the files that have that "ID Relation". As i said this sentence needs 7 seconds to get the data for a table with 9000 registers in the Table1.

For example with this values:

```
Table 1:
ID, Ticket Number
11   33
12   34
13   35

Table 2:

    ID, ID Relation  Ticket Number
    1   11             33
    2   11             34
    3   12             35
```

So as result i want:

```
T1.Ticket Number COUNT(T2.ID Relation)
33                2 
34                2
35                1
```

I think i am missing something, if someone that know more about sql can help me will be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want as a result ?

Comment: Edited and added a example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First if I have understood what you want is the number of ticket in a relation:

```
SELECT IDRelation, Count(TicketNumber)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY IDRelation
```

If you want T1.ID then :

```
SELECT T1.ID, Count(T2.IDRelation)
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT IDRelation, Count(TicketNumber)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY IDRelation) T2 ON T2.IDRelation = Table2.IDRelation
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 ON Table2.TicketNumber = T1.TicketNumber
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

But as you are doing INNER JOIN this is quite useless if you want ALL the tickets and count in how much relation they are, here is what you need to do :

```
SELECT T1.TicketNumber, Count(T2.IDRelation)
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.TicketNumber = T1.TicketNumber
INNER JOIN (SELECT IDRelation, Count(TicketNumber)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY IDRelation) T2 ON T2.IDRelation = Table2.IDRelation
GROUP BY T1.TicketNumber
```

Comment: Jean Doux, sorry for the delay but is not working for me. I make the 1st sql you tell me using only one table and the result of count is always 1 because the TicketNumber is not the same so counts only 1 row :(

Comment: Hmm i know what needs to be corrected. It's the number of tickets by relation for the first query.